# Spring Boot REST timeout, specific to one endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, timeout, settimeout

forgive my lack of Spring knowledge but I'd like to basically have 60 seconds be the default timeout for a Spring app, but have 120 seconds timeout for a particular endpoint.

FTR, to achieve the app-wide 60s read (in this case) timeout I am doing:

```java
        val requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory
        requestFactory.setReadTimeout(requestTimeout.toMillis.toInt)
```

(or, since this endpoint below is `@Async`, perhaps it's the `spring.mvc.async.request-timeout` setting in `application.yml` that's supplying the default, I'm not sure).

And then presumably on the endpoint/route in question, I will need to decorate it to specify a timeout of 120s or something like that?

Here's the endpoint class & method, which I wish to increase the timeout for:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = Array("/v1/contracts"), produces = Array(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
class ContractController @Autowired()(
...
    @Async
    @RequestMapping(value = Array("/{id}/students"), method = Array(RequestMethod.POST))
    def addContractStudents(
...
```

Any pointers will be gladly received

Comment: Are you sure you can use `@Async` On a controller method?

Comment: Yes(?) - this is code that's [apparently] been functionally correct in production for years but I'll stand to be corrected!